Checking for Differences between Tables and Making Changes
I have these two tables:
CREATE TABLE old_table 
(
    name1 VARCHAR(20),
    name2 VARCHAR(20),
    origin_date DATE,
    var1 VARCHAR(10),
    end_date DATE,
    status VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO old_table(name1, name2, origin_date, var1, end_date, status) 
VALUES
('red_1', 'red', '2010-01-01', 'aaa', NULL, 'active'),
('red_2', 'red', '2011-01-01', 'bbb', '2020-01-01', 'inactive'),
('blue_1', 'blue', '2005-01-01', 'ccc', '2020-01-01', 'inactive'),
('green_1', 'green', '2005-01-01', 'ddd', '2020-01-01', 'inactive'),
('purple_1', 'purple', '2001-01-01', 'fff', NULL, 'active'),
('pink_1', 'pink', '2002-01-01', 'ggg', NULL, 'active');


CREATE TABLE new_table 
(
    name1 VARCHAR(20),
    name2 VARCHAR(20),
    origin_date DATE,
    var1 VARCHAR(10),
    today DATE
);

INSERT INTO new_table (name1, name2, origin_date, var1, today) 
VALUES
('red_1', 'red', '2010-01-01', 'aaa', '2020-01-03'),
('orange_1', 'orange', '2012-01-01', 'zzz', '2020-01-01');

When comparing the new_table to the old_table:

pink and purple have no longer survived (end_date = new_table.today, status = inactive)
red has still survived (end_date = NULL, status = active)
orange has now appeared  (end_date = NULL, status = active)

The final result should look like this:



name1
name2
origin_date
var1
end_date
status




red_1
red
2010-01-01
aaa
NULL
active


red_2
red
2011-01-01
bbb
2020-01-01
inactive


blue_1
blue
2005-01-01
ccc
2020-01-01
inactive


green_1
green
2005-01-01
ddd
2020-01-01
inactive


purple_1
purple
2001-01-01
fff
2020-01-03
inactive


pink_1
pink
2002-01-01
ggg
2020-01-03
inactive


orange_1
orange
2012-01-01
zzz
NULL
active



I tried writing SQL code to reflect this requirements:
SELECT 
    o.name1,
    o.name2,
    o.origin_date,
    o.var1,
    CASE 
        WHEN n.name1 IS NULL THEN o.end_date 
        ELSE NULL 
    END AS end_date,
    CASE 
        WHEN n.name1 IS NULL THEN 'inactive' 
        ELSE 'active' 
    END AS status
FROM 
    old_table o
LEFT JOIN 
    new_table n ON o.name1 = n.name1

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    n.name1,
    n.name2,
    n.origin_date,
    n.var1,
    CASE 
        WHEN o.name1 IS NULL THEN NULL 
        ELSE n.today 
    END AS end_date,
    'active' AS status
FROM 
    new_table n
LEFT JOIN 
    old_table o ON n.name1 = o.name1
WHERE 
    o.name1 IS NULL;

Problem: The end_date for purple_1 and pink_1 are 2020-01-01 when they should be 2020-01-03:
    name1  name2 origin_date var1   end_date   status
    red_1    red  2010-01-01  aaa       <NA>   active
    red_2    red  2011-01-01  bbb 2020-01-01 inactive
   blue_1   blue  2005-01-01  ccc 2020-01-01 inactive
  green_1  green  2005-01-01  ddd 2020-01-01 inactive
 purple_1 purple  2001-01-01  fff 2020-01-01 inactive
   pink_1   pink  2002-01-01  ggg 2020-01-01 inactive
 orange_1 orange  2012-01-01  zzz       <NA>   active

Can someone please show me how to correct this?

AX is the after table
BX is the before table
TIP add an order by of some key field that is the same in both files followed by 1
SELECT 'AFTER', A.* FROM     
(SELECT * FROM AX            
EXCEPT                       
 SELECT * FROM BX) AS A      
UNION                        
SELECT 'BEFORE', B.* FROM    
(SELECT * FROM BX            
EXCEPT                       
 SELECT * FROM AX) AS B      

TIP add an order by of some key field that is the same in both files followed by 1  Example order by productID, 1  and you get a really nice after line followed by the before line.

After much re-jigging, I think I might have found an approach that targets these problems:
WITH updated_old_table AS (
    SELECT 
        old_table.name1,
        old_table.name2,
        old_table.origin_date,
        old_table.var1,
        CASE WHEN new_table.name1 IS NOT NULL AND old_table.status = 'active' THEN NULL 
             WHEN new_table.name1 IS NULL AND old_table.status = 'active' THEN (SELECT MAX(today) FROM new_table)
             ELSE old_table.end_date END AS end_date,
        CASE WHEN new_table.name1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'active' 
             WHEN new_table.name1 IS NULL AND old_table.status = 'active' THEN 'inactive'
             ELSE old_table.status END AS status
    FROM 
        old_table
    LEFT JOIN 
        new_table ON old_table.name1 = new_table.name1
),
new_entries AS (
    SELECT 
        name1,
        name2,
        origin_date,
        var1,
        NULL AS end_date,
        'active' AS status
    FROM 
        new_table
    WHERE 
        name1 NOT IN (SELECT name1 FROM old_table)
)
SELECT * FROM updated_old_table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM new_entries;

From here, purple_1 and pink_1 have the correct end_dates:
   name1  name2 origin_date var1   end_date   status
    red_1    red  2010-01-01  aaa       <NA>   active
    red_2    red  2011-01-01  bbb 2020-01-01 inactive
   blue_1   blue  2005-01-01  ccc 2020-01-01 inactive
  green_1  green  2005-01-01  ddd 2020-01-01 inactive
 purple_1 purple  2001-01-01  fff 2020-01-03 inactive
   pink_1   pink  2002-01-01  ggg 2020-01-03 inactive
 orange_1 orange  2012-01-01  zzz       <NA>   active

The other conditions are also satisfied:

active always has end_date as NULL, inactive has non null end_date
red_1 and orange_1 have no end_dates and are active

